# ArrayList<String> indexof alternative for giving all positions not only the first

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to look through a list of surnames and I need ALL positions of a name.

Lets say I have a List

```
List<String> surname=new ArrayList<String>();
```

and I am trying to get the index of "Smith" in the List.

I can use indexOf for this, but if there is more than one Smith I will only get the first index containing Smith.

```
surname.indexOf("Smith")
```

Is there are way to get all Positions in the List with Smith in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially have to loop through the list and collect the indices.

Here is one way to do using streams.

```
List<Integer> indices = IntStream.range(0, surname.size())
     .filter(idx -> surname.get(idx).equals("Smith"))
     .boxed()
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```